# Disabling a navigation drawer in double navigation drawer layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a double navigation drawer, one from left and one from right. I want to show right navigation drawer for some fragments only. so I want to disable it from others. This is my layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/orange"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/orange"/>

<!-- Listview for messages -->
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/message_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="#1C1C1C"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#1C1C1C"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
     />
```

I have seen

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

will lock the drawer. But how can I specifically lock one navigation drawer only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method overload `setDrawerLockMode (int lockMode, int edgeGravity)` allows you to specify which drawer to lock given its gravity. The overload `setDrawerLockMode (int lockMode, View drawerView)` lets you do the same by specifying the drawer View.